# AspectJ Integration with Spring & IntelliJ not working

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, aspectj, multi-module

I am currently working on a multi-module gradle project where all modules are dependent upon the `foo-common` module. Foo-common is the only one that does not have a main function. I want to integrate AOP with AspectJ and in order to do that I followed the following steps from the [Official IntelliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/aspectj.html):

- Using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2017.2 with the two plugins installed
- Installed AspectJ
- Created a library for `aspectjrt.jar` and added it as a dependency to `foo-common_main` and `foo-bar_main` modules using [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-a-library-for-aspectjrt-jar.html).
- Changed the compiler in IntelliJ from `javac` to `ajc` using [this documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-the-aspectj-compiler-ajc.html#settings).
- Enabled `Build | AspectJ Weaving`
- Created AspectJ Facets in the project structure for both `foo-common` and `foo-bar` with `Post-compile weave mode` enabled

My files look like below:

**Aspect.java (`foo-common` module)**

```
@Aspect
public class TraceAspect extends Pointcuts {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TraceAspect.class);

    @Before("call(* com.package.foo..*(..))")
    public void calling(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.trace("[CALL] " + joinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.package.foo..*(..))")
    public void initiating(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.trace("[EXEC] " + joinPoint.getSignature().toString());
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java (`foo-bar` module)**

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfiguration{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public DummyClientFactory dummyClientFactory() {
        return new dummyClientFactoryImpl();
    }
}
```

The project itself compiles and runs. If I try to modify `ApplicationConfiguration.java` to have manual log statements, that too works. And I can see IntelliJ using intelli-sense to point me to which advices connect to which methods. However I cannot see the logs being generated at all via the Aspects.

Comment: And have you enabled `TRACE` logging?

Comment: Also as long as you haven't included the aspect compilation in your maven/gradle build nothing much will happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, as I said, the manual logging part works fine. How would I go about including the aspect compilation in my gradle build? I have imported `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop`.

Comment: Including a starter won't enable compiling with Aspectj. You would need to include the proper plugin (check the aspect manual on how to do compile time weaving).

Comment: I notice aspectj support may be broken in Intellij 17, I have a properly setup of maven with spring boot and aspectj CTW, everything is good except intellij aop inspection failed. there's no aop dot on my editor anymore